# Update employee in Netsuite with Mule ESB

Tags: mule, netsuite

How to set department in employee on netsuite with mule ESB?

Comment: Unless you provide a link to the Netsuite API you intend to use, it will be hard for Mule users to help you.

Comment: I use this connector to NetSuite http://www.mulesoft.org/muleforge/netsuite-cloud-connector

Comment: Oh, OK. I've pinged 3miliano so he could look at this question and answer you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add Department to emplloyee looks like this

```
<netsuite: update-record recordType="EMPLOYEE" id="#internalId">
     <netsuite:attributes>
            <netsuite:attribute key="department" value="#[groovy: new com.netsuite.webservices.platform.core_2010_2.RecordRef( com.netsuite.webservices.platform.core_2010_2.types.RecordType.DEPARTMENT,'InternaldepartmentID','ExternalDepartmentID' );]"/>
      </netsuite:attributes>
</netsuite:update-record>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can definitely use NetSuite Cloud Connector to create an EMPLOYEE. The snippet for mule-config.xml would look something along the lines of this:

```
<netsuite:add-record recordType="EMPLOYEE">
      <netsuite:attributes>
          <netsuite:attribute key="firstName" value="#[variable:firstName]" />
          <netsuite:attribute key="lastName" value="#[variable:lastName]" />
          <netsuite:attribute key="email" value="#[variable:email]" />
      </netsuite:attributes>
  </netsuite:add-record>
```

You can find more information about our connector [here](http://www.mulesoft.org/muleforge/netsuite-cloud-connector).

A department can be set using a regular attribute:

```
<netsuite:attribute key="deparment" value="#[variable:departmentId]" />
```

Comment: I had to add a department employee.
I already know I know how to add a department employee.
Now there was a problem removing the department from the employee.

Comment: <netsuite:attribute key="deparment" value="#[variable:departmentId]" /> this not work, argument type mismatch - had objects of type "java.lang.String" but expected signature "com.netsuite.webservices.platform.core_2010_2.RecordRef"

Comment: Which version of the connector are you using?

Comment: I'm using mule-module-netsuite-1.0.

Comment: Can you file an issue in github.com/mulesoft/netsuite-connector? This is clearly not the way we intend this connector to work.